# Xamarin.Android Google Play Services dependency via AAR Binding

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 to write a Xamarin cross-platform app for Android and iOS. I need to make use of a 3rd party SDK written in Java for functionality related to Push messaging.  For the Android side of the solution, I have tried many, many things (over the course of days now), but have not been successful.  I would like to solve for the following solution:

- Have a PCL/Portable "myApp" library for common code/UI features.
- Have the  PCL/Portable library reference a "myApp.Android" assembly for Android-specific code.
- Have the  "myApp.Android" library reference a "myApp.Android.BindSDK" assembly for wrapping/binding to the 3rd party SDK.
  The myApp.Android.BindSDK assembly should (I believe):
- Use Xamarin's binding features to bind/wrap/include my 3rd party's SDK written in Java.  
  It has late bound dependencies on classes/functionality from Google Play services.
- Use NuGet to include Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm into the ".Android.BindSDK" project.

Ever since including Google Play Services to the myApp.Android.BindSDK project via NuGet, I get the following compilation error:

```
error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I have tried a lot of things posted on forums like cleaing the solution, deleting bin and obj folders, extracting the version.xml file from the JAR inside the AAR for Google Play, etc, etc, etc.  It still gets this build error.

Does anyone have a good example of how to create a Xamarin binding wrapper for an android/Java SDK that (itself) has dependencies on Google Play Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to create a working solution.

How-To is provided [in this post in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264285/xamarin-android-binding-to-3rd-party-sdk-with-dependencies/43622191#43622191).

**Key:**  The thing that I had been missing above seems to have been to include the 3rd party SDK's dependencies not in the Binding Assembly eg: "myApp.Android.BindSDK" used to wrap the SDK, but instead via NuGet into the Solution's Android assembly that was *referencing* the Binding Assembly eg: "myApp.Android".

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your binding project's `.csproj` contains the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets` as the resource task within that package is the one that extracts the Play Services version and adds it to your library's resources:

Example:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets')" />
```

Also check that the binding project manifest does *not* already contain an entry for `com.google.android.gms.version` as this should be auto-generated/merged by the build process:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

#### Workaround:

Note: I have never had to do this manually in my binding projects that included Play Services, I have come across some client's binding projects that cause the `.aar` resources merge process to fail on referenced packages (assuming there is a conflicting Play Services resource in the `.aar` but modifying the 3rd-party `.aar` is usually not worth it)

In the `Resources` directory, create a `values` folder and add a `values.xml` file with the `google_play_services_version` integer value:

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">10084000</integer>
```

Note: If the Google Play Services version changes you need to update the version value otherwise your app will end up throwing strange errors especially if you do InApp purchases....

Comment: I will check on my csproj file contents.I have tried extracting the version.xml file from the Google Play Services AAR and locating it inside my project in places like Resources\Values\version.xml, but it is not seen at runtime.

Comment: One thing that seems to get me around this issue is to bind to a Java component that basically wraps the SDK, and have the Xamarin binding component project target this wrapper 's AAR, and include all the JAR's  (like G.P.S.) involved as embedded resource JARs.  This limits/reduces my interface to the SDK, which is good, but the SDK was an AAR for a reason - it had image files in it.  Yet to see what the downside of lacking the images will be.  The solution doesn't feel like a certain best practice though...