# Xamarin.Android binding library Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a Xamarin binding library of a native android library which has a dependency on `Square okhttp3`

After adding the packages from Nuget packages, I found out that `Square okhttp3` library has a dependency on `square okio` library so i have also added the `square okio` library. My library packages list looks like this.

[image: Library packages list]

Once the binding library is build `library.dll` is generated, I used the `library.dll` file as a reference in an android app. After successfully running the app, the internal dependency package, `square okio` library is not resolved.

This is the error i am getting

[image]

**Workaround -**
A workaround i found to make it work is that, in the app if i add a reference of `square okio` library like the image below and run the app, it works. My sample app packages list looks like this

[image: Sample app package list]

Since I am trying to release a library to nuget repository and I wouldn't want the client to add another reference other than my library. Is there a way to make this work without adding any reference in the app?

My expertise is in Native Android and we are planning to support Xamarin. Since i am new to Xamarin I am stuck with this issue and not able to figure it out. Would really appreciate if there is a way to fix this. Thanks is advance

Comment: Can this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264285/xamarin-android-binding-to-3rd-party-sdk-with-dependencies) provide you some ideas?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Thanks. I did check out the link. But couldn't resolve it with nuget packages.